# How does Mashable.com displays/hides an element through Css?

Tags: css

I'm wondering how mashable.com hides its menu button - which appears in the top right hand corner - when the page is above a certain width and disappears when the page is below a certain width. A specific CSS rule:

```
html.no-touch .main-menu li.menu
{
  display: none;
}
```

takes precedence over the rule that displays the icon:

```
.navbar .nav > li 
{ 
   display:block;
   float: left;
}
```

but I can't see how it's doing it since disabling JavaScript appears to cause no ill effects and none of Css classes applied to parent elements seem to change. It seems that:

```
html.no-touch .main-menu li.menu
{
  display: none;
}
```

should always take precedence, but clearly doesn't and somehow this appears to have been accomplished solely with CSS and I'm curious to know how.

A graphic illustrating this is [here](http://oi46.tinypic.com/b96nv7.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using css [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) to show and hide different elements at different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Mashable.com uses Skeleton which is a very good resposive website design framework. It has well defined @media queries to hide or display divs depending on viewport size.

Comment: Mashable doesn't use any pre-existing responsive frameworks. All of our responsive stuff is in-house original.

Comment: I found it much similar to Skeleton framework, even naming in styles and how @media queries have been use. Yes, there are certain modifications.